# Jquery mobile. zoom/pinch image containers with a static header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am starting to use JQM on a project, and i have a requirement that image 'containers' are zoom/pinchable but keeping any header/footers static, sort of like a Google Map plugin.
Can someone tell me if this can be achieved in JQM at this point, and which plugins would help me with this ?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem. I found [this](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html) JQM plugin for Google Maps easy to use. You can zoom in/out of the map no problem.

By default JQM pages are zoomable itself. You can override this by specifying

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

**EDIT**
By default JQM pages itself are zoomable. You can override this with the above meta-tag. This way the page fits the screen and stays like this. There is a zoom-bug on iPad on orientationchange, so this page-fixing helps avoid any wrong size-increases/decresease on iPad. The Google Maps plugin area will load the normal GoogleMaps Map, which you can zoom in and out just like on regular Google Maps. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry not quite sure i understand. are you saying just use the google map plugin for any content that i want zoomable and just keep the headers static ? to clarify, how would i make a div zoomable while keeping the header static within jquery mobile. thanks!

Comment: yes. I just dropped the plugin on a page, can zoom the Google-Maps window in and out while the Jquery Mobile header/footer stay normal.

Comment: no i don't want to use the google map plugin at all. i just want the same behavior you see in that plugin, but scroll/zoom of an image gallery,with the header being static.

Comment: Have you tried photoswipe? www.photoswipe.com I think it has some of the functionalities you are looking for.

Comment: Photoswipe works but does not allow pinch and zoom.  Tried their demo on both android and an iPad.

Comment: It should allow pinch/zoom though. I haven't used it lately, but I could always zoom in by double tapping/zoom out by double tapping.